# Angular 5 Binding Attribute Using a Method?

Tags: angular, typescript

New to Angular and Typescript, trying to set a control's attribute using a method on my Component. Is it possible to send the Button control itself as an argument?

```
<input type="button" id="Button1" data-something="{{ GetSomething(this) }}">
```

And my method on my Component:

```
GetSomething(sender) {

    //do something with sender being the Button

    console.log(sender.id);

    return "garbage";
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? There are other ways to set classes using `*ngClass` or `[class.foo]` and the button *element* wouldn't really tell you anything.

Comment: Got it, assume class is a `data-` attribute instead. I used class just for this example. Will edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `this`, you meant the `HTMLElement` then the following might work: 
`<input type="button" id="Buttong1" #someBtn class="{{ GetButtonClass(someBtn)}}">`

Or read up on `ngClass` or `Class binding`:

- [Angular NgClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)
- [Angular Class Binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-targets)